# Xcode Objective C - How do I add a loading bar to my web browser for OS X?

Tags: cocoa, webkit, loading

I am making a web browser. Created a URL Text Bar and a WebView. But I had always wanted to know how to make a progress/loading bar that tells the user how much of the webpage loaded, how do I do this?

I have checked Apple's WebKit Development Guide but did not explain anything about loading bars.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working implementation, assuming you have an `@property` for the web view, a URL text field, and a progress indicator.

Your controller needs to be the resource delegate and policy delegate:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  self.webView.resourceLoadDelegate = self;
  self.webView.policyDelegate = self;
}
```

Make sure the URL field has the same URL as the page. We use this for tracking later.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
  self.urlField.stringValue = request.URL.absoluteString;

  [listener use];
}
```

Detect when a page starts loading.

```
- (id)webView:(WebView *)sender identifierForInitialRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
  if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:self.urlField.stringValue]) {
    [self.loadProgress setIndeterminate:YES];
    [self.loadProgress startAnimation:self];
  }
  return [[NSUUID alloc] init];
}
```

This will be called as new data comes in. Note the "length" parameter is the amount of length received in this chunk of data. You need to use dataSource to find the actual amount received so far. Also note that most web servers (as in, almost any dynamic webpage) will not return a content-length header, so you have to take a wild guess.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didReceiveContentLength:(NSInteger)length fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
  // ignore requests other than the main one
  if (![dataSource.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:self.urlField.stringValue])
    return;

  // calculate max progress bar value
  if (dataSource.response.expectedContentLength == -1) {
    self.loadProgress.maxValue = 80000; // server did not send "content-length" response. Pages are often about this size... better to guess the length than show no progres bar at all.
  } else {
    self.loadProgress.maxValue = dataSource.response.expectedContentLength;
  }
  [self.loadProgress setIndeterminate:NO];

  // set current progress bar value
  self.loadProgress.doubleValue = dataSource.data.length;
}
```

And this delegate method is called when the request has finished loading:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
  // ignore requests other than the main one
  if (![dataSource.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:self.urlField.stringValue])
    return;

  [self.loadProgress stopAnimation:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has an example on how to track resources as they load on this page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/ResourceLoading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002028-CJBEHAAG

Instead of printing out how many resources are left out of how many, you could use the numbers to set a progress bar.

BTW: This counting seems to be the only way to tell if a given page/URL has really finished loading.